# Copy or Clip command containing variable

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to figure out or see anywhere online where the `| clip` function would copy this string/variable $home

Everyday I have a Task Scheduler that opens PowerShell at logon and then I would initiate my .ps1 file to run programs to start off my day. I often change directory and the directory where my scripts are located has a long UNC path. So I'd like to make my life easier. This is what I have and this string is in my script:

```
$home = "C:\Users\Bender\onedrive - Futurama\tools\scripts" | clip
```

So when I need to go back to my root scripts path, I could just do this

```
cd $home
```

The problem is, the result of `| clip` is `C:\Users\Bender\onedrive - Futurama\tools\scripts`

Is it possible to copy this whole thing to clipboard?

```
$home = "C:\Users\Bender\onedrive - Futurama\tools\scripts"
```

Comment: `$home = "C:\..."; $home | clip`

Comment: How about (history).commandline | Clip after you run the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that in 2 commands.

```
$MyHome = "C:\Users\Bender\onedrive - Futurama\tools\scripts"
$MyHome | clip
```

For F8 purposes and / or convenience for you, you can always shorten multiple command into one line using the semi column separator.

```
$MyHome = "C:\Users\Bender\onedrive - Futurama\tools\scripts";$MyHome | clip
```

In both my examples, you are doing the following 2 operations.:

- The first command do the variable assignment.
- The second command send the assigned variable content to the clipboard.

Also, please note that the `$home` variable is an automatic variable reserved by Powershell.

Therefore, you cannot use write a value in that variable name, hence why in my example, I used `MyHome`. You can view a list of the reserved variable name in the reference below.

Your command therefore could not work because

- You are attempting to assign a value to a reserved variable name.
- You are actually assigning the result of the path passed through the clip command to your variable instead of the path itself. Since `clip` return nothing to the console, your variable assignment will always be `$null`

**References**

[About automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables)

> **$HOME**
>
> Contains the full path of the user's home directory. This variable is
>   the equivalent of the "$env:homedrive$env:homepath" Windows
>   environment variables, typically C:\Users\.

Comment: Colon or new line does the same thing for me. Thanks for the examples.